# Where can I ask questions about FPGA design?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm new to Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange. I'm interested in [FPGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field-programmable_gate_array) design stuff and already have some hot questions to ask.

On which site should I post my future questions about [FPGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field-programmable_gate_array), [VHDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHDL), [ModelSim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ModelSim), [VUnit](https://github.com/VUnit/vunit), etc.? Is Stack Overflow the right one, or is there a better one?  I've also seen VHDL stuff on *[Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour)*.

Comment: You could refine this meta question by looking at [the tag info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/site-recommendation/info): _Give an example question and title you want to ask. If you're going to be vague, it's not going to be the best advice and you may find yourself in rough seas._

Comment: There a [VUnit tag](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/vunit/info) on *Electrical Engineering* (with a plagiarised tag wiki).

Comment: If you want resources outside of SO and EE I recommend gitter. https://gitter.im/vhdl/General has less activity than SO and EE but the level is higher. Not so many please-do-my-homework type of questions. https://gitter.im/VUnit/vunit has more activity than SO and EE.

Answer (score 9):

Both Stack Overflow (SO) and Electrical Engineering (EE) have tags for `vhdl`, `fpga`, `modelsim` and `vunit`. You can learn about a site's tags by reading its `/tags` page.

Generally speaking, if your questions are more about designing FPGA's, I would lean toward EE.  If your questions are more about writing software (like C code) to run on an FPGA, I would lean toward SO.  If you have questions about running VHDL code simulations, questions are well-received on both sites. You can learn about what questions/topics are on-topic for a site by reading its `/help/on-topic` page.

Since you are new to Stack Exchange, you should spend significant time understanding how the sites work **before posting any questions**.  Take the [tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) for each site you are considering.  Then take a look at the
[Help center to see how to ask a good question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Also, look at some recent well-received questions in the tags of interest.  By well-received, I mean questions that do not have negative scores, are not closed and have well-received answers.

Comment: Very few people actually "design FPGAs", and they're certainly not asking questions here. Maybe you meant "designing *with* FPGAs"?

Comment: +1, a few more thoughts; some folks program FPGAs for [signal/image processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) and others for [scientific computing](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) in case it's an application question.